# Mapping null values result in default types values(Automapper ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, automapper

Recently I added **AutoMapper(7.0.1)** in our back end which by the way it does not use any ORM, just plain ADO.NET.

So I created mapping profiles for our models like this one:

```
public class UserMapping:Profile
{
    public UserMapping()
    {
        var mappingExpression = CreateMap<DataRow, User>();
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Id"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.Location, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Location"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.Team, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Team"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.LoginId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["LoginID"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.FirstName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["FirstName"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.LastName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["LastName"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.Email, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Email"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.Active, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Active"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.Date, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Date"]));
        mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.Entity, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Entity"]));
    }
}
```

and a utility class which just initiliaze the mapper.

```
 public static class Mapping
{
    public static void Configure()
    {

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
              cfg.AddProfile<UserMapping>();
                 //other profiles

            cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
            cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
        });
    }


}
```

The problems i have is that

- every string property even if it is null in the database its being returned as an empty string after the mapping
- Timespan? is being returned like 00:00:00 if it is null in the database
- bool? is being returned as false

Due to the fact that the way the front end is developed it needs the null values I need not to ignore the null values.

I found that I can use the

```
 cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
 cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
```

but unfortunately mapping process still does not return null values.
Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: Try ResolveUsing instead.

Comment: Hello Lucian thanks for your comment. I did but that didnt resolve anything.

Comment: I thought it would throw. Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching i found a workaround.

So for example for the properties i care about 
 i change the mapping expression from

```
mappingExpression.ForMember(m => m.CutOffTime, s => s.MapFrom(o => o["CutOffTime"]));
```

to

```
 mappingExpression.ForMember(m => m.CutOffTime, s => s.MapFrom(o => o["CutOffTime"] ==  DBNull.Value ? null : o["CutOffTime"] ));
```

Now the api returns null values as it should.

Comment: Yes, but there must have been an exception, because AM doesn't care about DBNull.

Comment: Lucian I wish i had seen an exception , i would at least had a direction to solve the issue and not try to find workarounds.

Comment: There is alway a first chance exception in the debugger, but MapFrom will catch that exception. ResolveUsing doesn't.